# cell renderer set column width

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to set width of a JTable column within its cell renderer? I have tried following code but it seems to do nothing.

```
//in main class where table defined;

table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(renderer);

//in renderer class;

setSize(10, getPreferredSize().height);
```

Comment: no, dont: never-ever change the state of the calling target (in getXXCellRendererComponent) Regard all parameters as strictly read-only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) its possible to set `JTable Column's` width this(very simple) way

```
TableColumnModel tcm = myTable.getColumnModel();
tcm.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(int);
```

2) I suggesting don't do that inside `TableRenderer`,

- because I don't see reason for repainting that every time when is Renderer fired
- and from your code that you posted here not really clear for me what / how / where / why

Comment: Actually I currently setting widht with this method however , I have about more than 20 tables totaly which uses this common renderer.This renderer sets the row number of the related table.And i was wondering if i can set its width in a common place for all these tables.Or any other method to set this column width centrally.

Comment: to try to aviod that, because Renderer works and repaint TableCell from lots of Events, there are two ways 1) determine TableColumn widht by calculate max_lengh from TableCell and for each TableColumn separatelly 2) manually wrote the code where you setPreferredSize for every TableColumns, 3) call this code only on start, and then by (from some built-in) refresh

Comment: Thank you for persuasive and plain explanation.